# Can I assign AOV for groups?

Tags: output

Is there any way to assign One [`AOV`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/aov.html) to a group of meshes? I want to assign AOV object-based and not material-based. There are several meshes with different materials in my scene and I have groups those so I want to assign AOV to group rather than manually going and applying for each material.